# NuGet Package Manager for custom project type

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am wondering if it is possible to enable the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio for custom project types.

I created a custom project type using Visual Studio Project System and when I right click the solution and select **Manage NuGet Packages...** I get the message '*Operation Failed. The project '[ProjectName]' is unsupported.*'

If I edit the project file and packages.config file in a text editor and run NuGet commands from the command line (restore, update) it works, but I would like to use the same package manager available to CS and VB projects. I hope there is a simple configuration to enable this.

I have seen tutorials on adding default packages to a project type but I want to allow a developer to use the manager to add new packages or update current ones. Anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: You will most likely need to modify the NuGet source code to enable this. The [MSBuildNuGetProjectSystemFactory class](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/7985322db49b11340ad4bf0c73247c9bd0096621/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio/ProjectSystems/MSBuildNuGetProjectSystemFactory.cs#L22-L28) shows some project systems that are supported in NuGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working after searching through all the imports in a Visual Basic project file and reverse engineering it. I found this in one of the imported targets.

```
  <!-- Import design time targets for Roslyn Project System. These are only available if Visual Studio is installed. -->
  <!-- Import design time targets before the common targets, which import targets from Nuget. -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualBasicDesignTimeTargetsPath Condition="'$(VisualBasicDesignTimeTargetsPath)'==''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Managed\Microsoft.VisualBasic.DesignTime.targets</VisualBasicDesignTimeTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VisualBasicDesignTimeTargetsPath)" Condition="'$(VisualBasicDesignTimeTargetsPath)' != '' and Exists('$(VisualBasicDesignTimeTargetsPath)')" />
```

After searching the imported file *$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Managed\Microsoft.Managed.DesignTime.targets* I found the following code.

```
<ProjectCapability Include="
                          AssemblyReferences;
                          COMReferences;
                          ProjectReferences;
                          PackageReferences;
                          SharedProjectReferences;
                          OutputGroups;
                          AllTargetOutputGroups;
                          VisualStudioWellKnownOutputGroups;
                          SingleFileGenerators;
                          DeclaredSourceItems;
                          UserSourceItems;" />
```

Adding the project capability to my project targets file got NuGet packages working! I'm not sure if all of them are needed but I couldn't narrow it down and the behaviour seems fine for my application.

Here is a list of some of the capabilities in case someone is searching. https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/overview/project_capabilities.md

**Edit**

Just to follow up with this issue after working with a solution for a while. More information on the capabilities can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/project-system-support

This will enable the NuGet package manager in VS but installing will fail. The solution would require implementing a lot classes to get it to function.

Outside of VS is a bit easier and works with NuGet client exe, however a small change is needed for custom project extensions. If you download the NuGet source you can see that the code only updates project files with a hard coded list of extensions. So you need to add your extension to the list if you update or restore on a solution or packages.config file. That way it will find you project file and perform the action on it.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.